# Including Trianglify in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, css

I am trying to make a background using trianglify. To do this I must include it in my project and use it properly. The thing I am trying to achieve is making a background like trianglify is supposed to.

here is my application.html.erb

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                           "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>



  </head>
  <body>

    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
     </div>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
    </div>

  </body>



</html>


<script>
    var Trianglify = require([]);
    var pattern = Trianglify({
        width: window.innerWidth, 
        height: window.innerHeight
    });
    document.body.appendChild(pattern.canvas())
</script>
```

Obviously it didn't put a background image . I checked with inspector and I get

```
    ReferenceError: require is not defined trianglify.js:8:4
ReferenceError: require is not defined localhost:3000:32:8
```

I guess it doesn't import something or I did something wrong?

To solve this error I downloaded http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.17/comments/require.js and now i get another error namely:

```
Error: Module name "delaunay-fast" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded require.js:167:16
Error: Module name "trianglify" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
```

Comment: Why are you "importing" it twice? you only need one. `trianglify.min.js = trianglify.js`

Comment: fixed that but the errors are still the same

Comment: i did write this in my application.js  *= require_trianglify

Comment: well I put it after you told me if I did that, and yes it doesn't change anything sadly.

Comment: the only thing I have on the background is a color anyway. I don't think it added a canvas because of the errors . But to be honest i don't know how to check if a canvas was added , mind telling me how ?

Comment: nope, i see no such thing :(

Comment: the require shows me that I don't have var delaunay = require('delaunay-fast'); ...

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't/don't use https://rails-assets.org/#/components/trianglify ?

Comment: @bear454 sorry bear, i really don't remember what trianglify even is or what I was trying to do 3 years ago :))) ... was just learning

Answer (score 0):

ahhh, I got your code resulting perfect outcome by putting that js in `app/assets/javascripts/` directory and, putting that script which calls `Trianglify` below end of the `body` tag, because at the time when `document.body.appendChild(pattern.canvas())` was trying to append child there was no existing body. Hope it helps.

Comment: where exactly in asset directory and how :D ?

Comment: at `app/assets/javascripts/` directory and remove that cdn link of js file from your .erb file.

Comment: but how do you put it in application.js ? :D that's what i don't know

Comment: you can't just add it with <script>

Comment: `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` adds every js file located at `app/assets/javascripts/`, so you don't need to do that.

Comment: so I put the script after the body and before the /html tag, also added both trianglify and trianglify.min in app/assets/javascripts but still i get the 2 require is not defined :( i am so bad

Comment: don't put both, they will conflict each other.

Comment: same ReferenceError: require is not defined trianglify.js:9:4. Must I install or do something else except puting the trianglify.js in app/assets/javascripts and writing that script in the .erb file. (I did not install anything or something like that)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76799/discussion-between-lucian-tarna-and-sadaf2605).

Comment: DId you remove that cdn js?

Comment: also restart your server, because it worked here. So probably you are missing something.